# Cannot login to lxc container

Tags: containers, fedora, lxc

I have created an lxc container in fedora-20 with default config file and default fedora template.

```
lxc-create -n root -t fedora
```

When I try to start the container I am greeted with username and password prompt.

In ubuntu it seems they use default "ubuntu" as username and password. I tried with different combination of password like "root" as specified in template but not able to login.

This is the output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lxc-start -n root
systemd 208 running in system mode. (+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ)
Detected virtualization 'lxc'.

Welcome to Fedora 20 (Heisenbug)!

Set hostname to <root.localdomain>.
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems.
[  OK  ] Created slice Root Slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice User and Session Slice.
[  OK  ] Created slice System Slice.
[  OK  ] Reached target Slices.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[  OK  ] Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[  OK  ] Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
Failed to open /dev/autofs: No such file or directory
Failed to initialize automounter: No such file or directory
[FAILED] Failed to set up automount Arbitrary Executable File...utomount Point.
See 'systemctl status proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount' for details.
Unit proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount entered failed state.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on udev Control Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Listening on Journal Socket.
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
         Mounting Debug File System...
         Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
         Mounting Huge Pages File System...
         Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
         Mounting FUSE Control File System...
         Starting Create static device nodes in /dev...
         Mounting Configuration File System...
         Starting Journal Service...
[  OK  ] Started Journal Service.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
         Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
         Mounting Temporary Directory...
[  OK  ] Started Apply Kernel Variables.
[  OK  ] Mounted Debug File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[  OK  ] Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[  OK  ] Started Create static device nodes in /dev.
[  OK  ] Mounted Configuration File System.
[  OK  ] Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[  OK  ] Mounted Temporary Directory.
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
         Starting Configure read-only root support...
         Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
<30>systemd-udevd[24]: starting version 208
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save Random Seed.
[  OK  ] Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[  OK  ] Started Configure read-only root support.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local File Systems.
         Starting Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage...
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
[  OK  ] Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Reboot/Shutdown...
<46>systemd-journald[18]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[  OK  ] Started Trigger Flushing of Journal to Persistent Storage.
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Reboot/Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting Login Service...
         Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Getty on tty3...
[  OK  ] Started Getty on tty3.
         Starting Getty on tty4...
[  OK  ] Started Getty on tty4.
         Starting Getty on tty2...
[  OK  ] Started Getty on tty2.
         Starting Getty on tty1...
[  OK  ] Started Getty on tty1.
         Starting Console Getty...
[  OK  ] Started Console Getty.
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
         Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Started Login Service.
[  OK  ] Reached target Multi-User System.

Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
Kernel 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 on an x86_64 (console)

root login: root
Password: 
Last failed login: Thu Jun  5 08:37:20 UTC 2014 on console
There were 3 failed login attempts since the last successful login.

Cannot make/remove an entry for the specified session

Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
Kernel 3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64 on an x86_64 (console)

root login:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try checking /var/lib/lxc/$container_name/

There should be a file named `tmp_root_pass` that will expire upon your first successful login.

ls /var/lib/lxc/ovs/
config  rootfs  tmp_root_pass

Comment: Nope .. no such file. Example: my container is "cn1".  All I see in /var/lib/lxc/cn1/rootfs/ folder are the various os related folders like bin/ dev/ home/ etc.  But no such file as tmp_root_pass.

Comment: Try up one directory :) (/var/lib/lxc/cn1)

Answer (score 0):

For me `lxc-attach -n root` works. It chroots into the system and you can set the root password from there.